# How to make the mozilla progressbar the same as chrome

Tags: css, firefox, webkit

I'm using the  tag but in mozilla it looks like this:
[image]

but i want to make it like this: [image]

the code im using for the lastone:

```
progress[value] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Any idea how to make then the same?

Comment: I'd start with looking into [CSS reset solutions](https://www.google.nl/search?q=css+reset+for+html5&oq=css+reset+for+html5&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4858j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
progress::-moz-progress-bar { background: green; }
progress {
   height: 50px;
   padding: 0;
   border: none;
}
```

Comment: what about the height?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2ppq1k The width and height will work for the green bat inside but not for the border/box outside